# How to send emails from mail.domain.com to mail2.domain.com

Tags: wordpress, email, dns

Recently my company's website was moved to another server, due to old server. The website is directing emails to `mail2.domain.example` (sent to Thunderbird). When the website was move to the other, the website is sending the emails to `mail.domain.example`.

I tried forwarding the emails but the Cpanel in the server won't let me as it is sending the emails inside the `mail.domain.example` only. Is there another way to send `mail.domain.example` to `mail2.domain.example`, the one who done it before has already left the company, so I was assigned to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem by using SMTP (WP Mail SMTP) and updated my WordPress to the latest version. Works like a charm.

I realize the problem when I'm sending email using gmail, gmail sends the emails to mail2.domain.example, so I used the google SMTP to forward messages to mail2.